# Angular filter rxjs, it's not filtering correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to implement the filter operator from rxjs, to filter out different portflios ALL | APP | WEB |API
[image]

I expect the filter to filter out the portfolios according to the property type:
[image]

Here is the filter implemmentation

Why does the click not filter portfolios here? what concept I'm I missing?

```
 portfolios: IPortfolio[] = [];
  portfolioType: 'all' | 'app' | 'web'|'api' = 'all';
  errorMessage = '';
  sub!: Subscription;
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.portFolioService.getPortfolioData().subscribe({
      next: portfolios => {
        this.portfolios = portfolios;
        filter((portfolio: IPortfolio) => portfolio.type === this.portfolioType);
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    })
  }
```

and the view html has

```
<ul id="portfolio-filters">
  <li [class.filter-active]="portfolioType == 'all'" (click)="portfolioType = 'all'">All</li>
  <li [class.filter-active]="portfolioType == 'app'" (click)="portfolioType = 'app'">APP</li>
  <li [class.filter-active]="portfolioType == 'web'" (click)="portfolioType = 'web'">WEB</li>
  <li [class.filter-active]="portfolioType == 'api'" (click)="portfolioType = 'api'">API</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `.pipe()` where you can put a `map` to transform the portfolios with `filter`. Placing it as an expression inside the `next` callback will have no effect.

```
this.portfolioService.getPortfolioData().pipe(
  map(portfolios => portfolios.filter(portfolio => this.portfolioType === portfolio.type))
).subscribe(portfolios => {
  // portfolios are filtered now
})
```

Comment: This is working well, but in my json I dont have a portfolio with type ALL. When I use if statement in subscribe or map, neither works.
but when I assign the portfolioType default to say like API, the portfolios with API show.

Answer (score 0):

As your instance type IPortfolio[] is an array, you should use Array.prototype.filter to filter your portfolios:

```js
 portfolios: IPortfolio[] = [];
  portfolioType: 'all' | 'app' | 'web'|'api' = 'all';
  errorMessage = '';
  sub!: Subscription;
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.portFolioService.getPortfolioData().subscribe({
      next: portfolios => {
        this.portfolios = portfolios.filter(portfolio => portfolio.type === this.portfolioType)
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    })
  }
```

Comment: Nothing is shown on the view with this approach

Comment: Then adjust your portfolioType and the predicate callback accordingly. This is plain filtering, just like you tried before

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reading rxjs Documentation, I got the method to best work:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IPortfolio } from '../portfolio';
import { PortfolioService } from '../portfolio.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-section-portfolio',
  templateUrl: './section-portfolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./section-portfolio.component.scss']
})
export class SectionPortfolioComponent implements OnInit {

  private unsubscribe$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private portfolioService: PortfolioService
  ) { }

  private portfolios: IPortfolio[] = [];
  public portfolios$: BehaviorSubject<Array<IPortfolio>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<IPortfolio>>([]);
  portfolioType: string = 'all';

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllPortfolios();
  }

  private getAllPortfolios () {
      this.portfolioService.getPortfolioData().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe((portfolios: Array<IPortfolio>) => {
          this.portfolios = portfolios;
          this.portfolios$.next(this.portfolios);
      })
  }

  public applyFilter (filter: string) {
    this.portfolioType = filter
    if (filter === 'all') {
      this.portfolios$.next(this.portfolios);
      return;
    }
    const filteredPortfolios = this.portfolios.filter(portfolio => portfolio.type === filter);
    this.portfolios$.next(filteredPortfolios);
    console.log(this.portfolioType)
  }
}
```

and in the template

```
        <ul id="portfolio-filters">
           <li [ngClass]="portfolioType === 'all'? 'filter-active':''"(click)="applyFilter  ('all')">All</li>
          <li [ngClass]="portfolioType === 'app'? 'filter-active':''"  (click)="applyFilter ('app')">APP</li>
          <li [ngClass]="portfolioType === 'web'? 'filter-active':''"  (click)="applyFilter ('web')">WEB</li>
          <li [ngClass]="portfolioType === 'api'? 'filter-active':''" (click)="applyFilter ('api')">API</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div *ngFor="let portfolio of (portfolios$|async)">
<!-- End Portfolio Section -->
```